# UBUNTU 16.04 (64 bit) with AMDGPU-PRO-16.50-362463 generates continuous stream of system errors

Tags: drivers, 16.04, graphics, 64-bit, amd-graphics

Noticed a *change* on my 16.04 (64 bit) rig running *Unity*. Examined *syslog* and *xorg.0.log* and noted an almost continuous stream of errors being logged.

Sample log file output... For *syslog*:

```
Dec 31 10:08:08 XXLOWS01 kernel: [  268.882697] [drm:amdgpu_crtc_page_flip] crtc:0[ffff880210294000], pflip_stat:AMDGPU_FLIP_PENDING, work: ffff8800d73c5cc0,
Dec 31 10:08:08 XXLOWS01 kernel: [  268.883451] [drm:dm_page_flip] dm_page_flip Flipping to hi: 0x0, low: 0xfb810000 
Dec 31 10:08:08 XXLOWS01 kernel: [  268.883456] [drm:amdgpu_flip_work_func] crtc:0[ffff880210294000], pflip_stat:AMDGPU_FLIP_SUBMITTED, work: ffff8800d73c5cc0,
Dec 31 10:08:08 XXLOWS01 kernel: [  268.887753] [drm:dm_pflip_high_irq] dm_pflip_high_irq - crtc :0[ffff880210294000], pflip_stat:AMDGPU_FLIP_NONE, work: ffff8800d73c5cc0,
Dec 31 10:08:08 XXLOWS01 kernel: [  268.899866] [drm:drm_mode_addfb2] [FB:76]
Dec 31 10:08:08 XXLOWS01 kernel: [  268.899878] [drm:get_dm_commit_action] crtc_state_flags: enable:1, active:1, planes_changed:1, mode_changed:0,active_changed:0,connectors_changed:0
Dec 31 10:08:08 XXLOWS01 kernel: [  268.899881] [drm:get_dm_commit_action] crtc_state_flags: enable:1, active:1, planes_changed:1, mode_changed:0,active_changed:0,connectors_changed:0
Dec 31 10:08:08 XXLOWS01 kernel: [  268.899886] [drm:get_dm_commit_action] crtc_state_flags: enable:1, active:1, planes_changed:1, mode_changed:0,active_changed:0,connectors_changed:0
Dec 31 10:08:08 XXLOWS01 kernel: [  268.899896] [drm:get_dm_commit_action] crtc_state_flags: enable:1, active:1, planes_changed:1, mode_changed:0,active_changed:0,connectors_changed:0
```

For *xorg.0.log*:

```
[   105.579] (WW) AMDGPU(0): amdgpu_dri2_flip_event_handler: Pageflip completion event has impossible msc 6231 < target_msc 6232
[   105.595] (WW) AMDGPU(0): amdgpu_dri2_flip_event_handler: Pageflip completion event has impossible msc 6232 < target_msc 6233
[   105.787] (WW) AMDGPU(0): amdgpu_dri2_flip_event_handler: Pageflip completion event has impossible msc 6243 < target_msc 6244
```

Configuration:

```
Processor: Intel® Core™ i5-2400 CPU @ 3.10GHz × 4
Graphics card: AMD Radeon (TM) RX 460 Graphics
Driver: amdgpu-pro-16.50-362463
```

I've uninstalled the amdgpu-pro driver *successfully* and reverted to the *standard* drivers (no or limited graphics acceleration) and *syslog*/*xorg.0.log* errors stopped. I *installed* the most recent *AMDGPU-PRO-16.50-362463* drivers and the log errors *returned*.

Would like to see if there is anyone out there with a solution (apart switching graphics card architecture).

Comment: Related [posting](https://community.amd.com/thread/205475) on the AMD site.

Comment: Adding  "TearFree" "on" to the 10-amdgpr-pro.conf eliminated the stream of error messages in the Xorg.0.log. However still trying to figure out how to stop the stream of errors on _syslog_. Posting indicates `Regarding the syslog flood, this was caused by two OpenCL executables running at the same time - and by reducing to one - these errors have also stopped.` Not sure how to fix this latter point. Clues?

Comment: syslog errors still continue to occur; still looking for solution. Recent sample just after reboot as be found here http://paste.ubuntu.com/23780230/.

Comment: The prints are coming from DRM_DEBUG_KMS. Did you enable DRM debug prints for your kernel? In particular DRM_UT_KMS (0x4)?

Comment: Firstly, appreciate the support. In relation to "enable DRM debug prints" - no, at least not consciously. I'm an "end user". I bought the AMD graphics card; noticed it didn't work "out of the box" and installed the AMDGPU-PRO driver. The the flood of error messages in the log started.

Comment: Update: Uninstalled _amdgpu-pro_ per AMD documentation. Rebooted with consequent loss of screen resolution. _However, the **syslog** and **xorg.conf** flood of debug messages has stopped._ I've tried reinstall of the most recent _amdgpu-pro_ driver with no success - the flood of debug messages restarts. Now will try earlier releases to see if this was something introduced in _amdgpu-pro-16.50-362463_.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! Uninstalled the *amdgpu-pro-16.50-362463* driver and replaced with the ***new*** *amdgpu-pro-16.60-379184* driver. The ***syslog*** flood of DRM debug messages have ***stopped***.  Installing the new driver seems to replace the 10-amdgpu-pro.conf file, so need to revise  per https://community.amd.com/thread/205475 to stop Xorg.0.log "flood". Tnx to those that have helped debug - and especially those that have revised the driver!!